# w3c xml naming standards

Tags: xml, w3c

Where does the w3c state that xml tags must not start with a number?

I have looked through the http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#uniqattspec document but I don't see it.

Comment: I haven't look at the specs but XML node names are likely to match variable names or value objects which usually don't allow numbers as a first character. So yeah it sounds a bit dirty to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar) is the part of the spec your are looking for.

Comment: Disallowed initial characters for Names include digits, diacritics, the full stop and the hyphen.

Comment: @user1354345 isn't it what have you asked?

Comment: @user1354345 You do realize that a "digit" is a number, right?